# From a moral perspective, how would a Catholic moral theologian justify modesty?

Tags: catholicism, morality, catholic-catechism

From the Catechism of Pope St. John Paul the Great:

> §2521 Purity requires *modesty*, an integral part of temperance. Modesty protects the intimate center of the person. It means refusing to unveil what should remain hidden. It is ordered to chastity to whose sensitivity it bears witness. It guides how one looks at others and behaves toward them in conformity with the dignity of persons and their solidarity.

But according to playwright Alan Bennett, "All modesty is false modesty; otherwise, it wouldn't be called modesty". This paradoxicality can be seen in the self-refuting nature of the sentence "I am humble".

How would a Catholic moral theologian justify modesty in light of its paradoxicality?

Comment: I don't see how modesty is paradoxical, although I agree that the statement "I am humble" is paradoxical. How is modesty supposed to be paradoxical, besides the claim of some random person?

Comment: @Null That's another question: should Alan Bennet's claim be discounted, and for what reasons?

Comment: I don't see how modesty is paradoxical, so I put little weight in that opinion as is. Does he give reasons why he thinks "all modesty is false modesty"? Do you know of anyone else who thinks the same (and hopefully gives reasons)? Without some reason(s) to think he is right, this seems as flimsy a reason to ask a Catholic moral theologian to "justify modesty" as asking someone to "justify" that chocolate is better than vanilla rather than vice versa.

Comment: @Null When St. Abraham the Patriarch wanted to be modest, he lied. (Genesis 20:2-12)

Comment: That wasn't modesty, that was just lying. What is "false" about a person simply wearing appropriate clothing so as to avoid exposing too much of his or her intimate body parts?

Comment: @Null Abraham didn't lie for no reason. Pharaoh was being nosey and lying was a way to shut down his perverted curiosity. The moral of the story (and why the Creator included it in Holy Scripture) is that there's a logical connection between falseness and modesty. The same story repeats later with his son Isaac (Genesis 26:7) reinforcing this connection.

Comment: There *may* be a connection between falseness and modesty in certain instances, but I do not see how there is a *logical* connection between them. Again, what is "false" about a person simply wearing appropriate clothing so as to avoid exposing too much of his or her intimate body parts?